# Need to add new items under the existing XML file using C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

I need to add new items in the existing file using C#, Could any please provide best logic to do it in using C#.
**Below is my XML File (Input)=**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FileSetting xmlns="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM" xmlns:xs="http://www.M1.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Files>
      <File Section="Section 1" Method="Complete" Location="Total 1">
         <Columns>
            <Profile Method="DataCollection" Item="All" />
         </Columns>
      </File>
      <!--  <File Section="Section 2" Method="Complete" Location="Total 2">
    <Columns>
      <Profile Method= "DataCollection" Item="All"/>
     </Columns>
  </File> -->
      <File Section="Section 3" Method="Complete" Location="Main">
         <Columns>
            <Profile Method="DataCollection" Item="All" />
         </Columns>
      </File>
   </Files>
</FileSetting>
```

Here in my existing XML file I want to add new File item under the Files, so
**I am expecting output as=**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FileSetting xmlns="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM" xmlns:xs="http://www.M1.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Files>
      <File Section="Section 1" Method="Complete" Location="Total 1">
         <Columns>
            <Profile Method="DataCollection" Item="All" />
         </Columns>
      </File>
      <!--  <File Section="Section 2" Method="Complete" Location="Total 2">
    <Columns>
      <Profile Method= "DataCollection" Item="All"/>
     </Columns>
  </File> -->
      <File Section="Section 3" Method="Complete" Location="Main">
         <Columns>
            <Profile Method="DataCollection" Item="All" />
         </Columns>
      </File>
      <File Section="Section 4" Method="NotComplete" Location="Test5">
         <Columns>
            <Profile Method="DataCollecter" Item="Partial" />
         </Columns>
      </File>
   </Files>
</FileSetting>
```

Could anyone please provide the best logic to do it in C#?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            XElement files = doc.Descendants(ns + "Files").FirstOrDefault();

            XElement newFile = new XElement(ns + "File", new object[] {
                new XAttribute("Section", "Section 4"),
                new XAttribute("Method", "NotComplete"),
                new XAttribute("Location", "Test5"),
                new XElement(ns + "Columns", new object[] {
                    new XElement("Profile", new object[] {
                        new XAttribute("Method", "DataCollecter"),
                        new XAttribute("Item", "Partial")
                    })
                })
            });

            files.Add(newFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Its working.

but Im getting xmlns="" also with File name  as below.

 <File Section="Section 4" Method="NotComplete" Location="Test5" xmlns="">
         <Columns>
            <Profile Method="DataCollecter" Item="Partial" />
         </Columns>
      </File>

I dont need this in output , as there any way that we will not get it in the output?? Thank you so much for the help

Comment: After I posted answer I thought that may happen.  I added "ns +" in two locations in the code.

Comment: If there is a change in the XML file and if the XML has some extra nodes so its removing those node in the output, is there any way we can add item under the Files and it should not effect the other nodes if XML has some other node as well? Thanks in Advance for the great help

Comment: Code above should not be removing any nodes.  You have comments in the original xml that may look like nodes are being deleted, but those nodes are comments.